# Excel - why my grid is automatically filled

Tags: excel

I have a grid with headers. I added formula to calculate rows from another sheet. Formula looks like this:
`=SUMIFS(CHECK!F:F;Nike!C:C;[@Shoe];Black!D:D;[@Col])`

It is: If there is a row `Nike` in `Shoe` column and `Black` in `Col` column in CHECK sheet then put here summary from F column.

And it works fine. The problem is, than when i paste that Forumula in for example B3, whole B column in grid contains that Formula.

I want to have That formula in B3. Another formula in B4, another in B5 etc. But wherever i paste that in Bx, every Bx column contains that. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are using a table. if you just use use the undo button it will only have your formula in B3.
Of course you have to use the undo after it auto populates